# What is the difference between a string and a direct value for a MSBuild property?

Tags: msbuild

What is the difference between using a `System.String` and writting the property value directly, for example:

```xml
<PropertyGroup
  <DefineConstants>$([System.String]::new('Debug;Lang=EN'))/DefineConstants>
  <DefineConstants>Debug;Lang=EN</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I noticed that a build tool was called differently, namely:

1. `candle -d"Debug;Lang=EN" ...`
2. `candle -dDebug -dLang=EN ...`

I do not think this is relevant, but for what it is worth the candle task is used as

```
<Candle
  SourceFiles="@(_CompileWithObjectPath)"
  DefineConstants="$(DefineConstants);$(SolutionDefineConstants);$(ProjectDefineConstants);$(ProjectReferenceDefineConstants)"
  ...
```

(Note that this is a minimal test case, in reality I call a property function which returns a string.)